# What driver should I choose for my Nvidia GPU?

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

Here are my current options

[image]

I want to know which one do you prefer is better at performance since i still don't understand how they work.

Also i want to know how to update to the latest version of the driver.

Edit: I believe this is not a duplicate of [remove old graphics card, and install new one in ubuntu14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538571/remove-old-graphics-card-and-install-new-one-in-ubuntu14-04), because william was asking how to install the new one and remove the old one, where i was asking which one was better and what are the differences between the 3 choices in my Additional Drivers tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nouveau is a free open source driver for Nvidia cards that is built by the community, this is pre-installed and should be changed for the average user.

Nvidia-331 is the fully tested version from Nvidia

Nvidia-331-updates is the same driver but with all latest updates, so potential bugs.

I recommend Nvidia-331-updates for performance and if you have trouble just change it.

Updates come from the repo like other apps.

For a quick install you can run in a terminal

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates`

or

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```